# How to change size of website respect to screen and maintaining standard resolution?

Tags: html, css

I created one website of 1920 x 1080 resolution using CSS HTML my laptop screen size is 1280 x 610 how can I fit my complete site on my laptop screen and other screens?

Comment: Design everything (from the start preferably) in terms of relative units - percentages, vmin, rems and don't use absolute units like px. As you already have a site designed for a specific aspect ratio and fixed px size, go through seeing what you can convert to relative units fairly easily, and if the design just doesn't work on say narrow devices like phones you may have to consider media queries - but as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design everything (from the start preferably) in terms of relative units - percentages, vmin, rems and don't use absolute units like px.

As you already have a site designed for a specific aspect ratio and fixed px size, go through seeing what you can convert to relative units fairly easily.

If the design just doesn't work on say narrow devices like phones you may have to consider media queries - but only after you've made everything relative.

Answer (score 0):

Use width and height in percents. For html and body set height and width to 100%.